# popto page after few seconds in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I am very new to ionic. Just learning it. Basically I have two pages, welcome and home. First welcome page gets loaded.

I want to load home page after 2-3 seconds when welcome page load. Same I have done using setTimeout in JavaScript.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad WelcomePage');
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.navCtrl.popToRoot(home);
    }, 2500);
}
```

The above code not working. Seems like typo error in poptoroot. What can I try to fix this?

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: can't find variable: home

Comment: then home is not declared. and judging by that code you pasted is not declared on that function.

Comment: alright i have added the home page variable and it is working. Means when page loads after 2.5 sec it went to home page but when i go back to welcome page it stays there. I was hoping that whenever i move to welcome page it needs to load home page after 2.5 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to declare your variable "home" since it's not defined. Then to have the home page loaded when you get to the welcome page you need to use "ionViewDidEnter". Your problem is that "ionViewDidLoad" only runs once, which is when the page is created, but "ionViewDidEnter" will run even if the page is created or cached.